# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, polyfills

i'm trying to install this package https://github.com/shwilliam/vue-scrollin to my laravel + vue project. after compiling with laravel mix, the following error appeared:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in
> '\node_modules\vue-scrollin\dist'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules
> by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module
> and configure a polyfill for it. If you want to include a polyfill,
> you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "timers": require.resolve("timers-browserify") }'
> - install 'timers-browserify' If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "timers": false }

I followed the given instructions but it gives me the same errors.

webpack.mix.js

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
        .sass('resources/css/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css')
        .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
            //
        ])
        .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));
```

webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        fallback: { "timers": require.resolve("timers") }
    },
};
```

package.json

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
        "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-3",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.7",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bulma": "^0.9.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "particles.vue3": "^1.3.1",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.8",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
        "vue": "^3.0.5",
        "vue-loader": "^16.1.2",
        "vue-router": "^4.0.5",
        "vue-scrollin": "^0.1.2",
        "timers-browserify": "^2.0.12"
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a `timers` dependency. The warning also suggests `timers-browserify`, not `timers`.

Comment: i don't know how to install it, the timers from npm is not the one needed, and anyway it seems that the timers package is already present

Comment: You already have `timers-browserify` as a dependency, so it should be installed already. You just need to update your usage from `require('timers')` to `require('timers-browserify')` so that it matches the suggestion in the warning.

Comment: understood thanks, but the require('timers') is used from the vue-scrolling package. do you know if it is possible to override it without forking and editing the package manually?

Comment: That's what the config is doing: specifying the fallback for `timers` that `vue-scrollin` is trying to load. What's the result when you tried the suggestion?

Comment: ah ok, now I understood clearly. it is working thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you managed to solved like the example above? I'm facin a similar issue with `stream-browserify` lol

Comment: you just need to put in your webpack.config.js the fallback related to your dependency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it. `webpack.config.js` should be:

```js
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        fallback: { "timers": require.resolve('timers-browserify') }
    },
};
```

Just change the package in the `require.resolve()` to what the warning suggests.

**For anyone who comes here** with a polyfills-problem or about to migrate from webpack 4 to 5, [here's the PR with a list of removed polyfills](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/8460/commits/a68426e9255edcce7822480b78416837617ab065#diff-4e3db817402e6923cfe42d171bb94b704d7d7b0d52ee64d71540063130594c38R12)